# How to list all classes and methods/functions in a package - with a full folder/file path?

Tags: python, file, module

(for the purpose of better understanding the structure of package)

Let's say we have some package/module (say, `somemodule`), with the following structure:

```
somemodule
-- file1.py
      fo(x) # a function
-- file2.py
      bar(x) # a function
-- dir1
---- file3.py
         A  # a class
            fun(y) # some method
            _bo(y) # some "hidden" method
```

I would like some output like:

```
path            name      type
/file1.py       fo(x)     function
/file2.py       bar(x)    function
/dir1/file3.py  A         class
/dir1/file3.py  A.fun(y)  method
/dir1/file3.py  A._bo(y)  method
```

Given that I'm a novice in Python, I have no idea how to go about constructing such information, and would be happy for help.

The closest I found online was:

- [How to list all functions in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/how-to-list-all-functions-in-a-module) - which didn't help enough, since it only shows some functions (not the hidden ones), doesn't show methods within classes, and doesn't show file path (i.e.: neither dir, or help, or some of the other suggested functions seem to be up to the task).
- [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) - shows files, but not for a module (not the functions/classes/methods within the object)

Comment: Start by reading [What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7948494/4046632). What you show (the structure) is a package, not module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an example on how to do it:

```
import inspect
import TestModule


def recusive_module_search(module):
    members = inspect.getmembers(module)

    for name, member in members:
        if inspect.ismodule(member):
            # Dont go too deep :)
            if member is module:
                recusive_module_search(member)
        elif inspect.isfunction(member):
            file = inspect.getfile(member)
            print(file, function_signature_string(member), "function")
        elif inspect.isclass(member):
            file = inspect.getfile(member)
            print(file, function_signature_string(member), "class")
            class_members = inspect.getmembers(member)
            for name, class_member in class_members:
                if inspect.isfunction(class_member):
                    member_args = inspect.signature(class_member)
                    print(file, member.__name__ + "." + function_signature_string(class_member), "method")

def function_signature_string(member):
    parameters = inspect.signature(member).parameters
    return member.__name__ + "(" + ', '.join(str(x) for x in parameters.values()) + ")"

recusive_module_search(TestModule)
```

output:

```
C:\Users\mclea\src\PydanticMongoEngine\TestModule\functions.py Test(x: int, y: float) class
C:\Users\mclea\src\PydanticMongoEngine\TestModule\functions.py Test.__init__(self, x: int, y: float) method
C:\Users\mclea\src\PydanticMongoEngine\TestModule\functions.py Test.print_x(self) method
C:\Users\mclea\src\PydanticMongoEngine\TestModule\functions.py hi(x: int) function
C:\Users\mclea\src\PydanticMongoEngine\TestModule\SubModule\test.py test_fn(hello: str) function
```

Continue as desired :)

Comment: @TalGalili No worries, I had fun making it lol

Answer (score 0):

try dir(module) if there are sub modules you have to iterate and traverse in all classes

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is great when the package references relevant functions/methods. But if they are not invoked by `__init__`, then they won't be listed.

After a bunch of digging I came up with the following solution. Probably not ideal, but worked for my use-case, so I'm re-sharing it here for others to use/improve upon.

```
def get_functions_and_methods(path):
    """
    Given a .py file path - returns a list with all functions and methods in it.

    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73239026/256662
    """
    import ast

    with open(path) as file:
        node = ast.parse(file.read())

    def show_info(functionNode):
        function_rep = ''
        function_rep = functionNode.name + '('

        for arg in functionNode.args.args:
            function_rep += arg.arg + ','

        function_rep = function_rep.rstrip(function_rep[-1])
        function_rep += ')'
        return function_rep

    result = []
    functions = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
    classes = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.ClassDef)]

    for function in functions:
        result.append(show_info(function))

    for class_ in classes:
        methods = [n for n in class_.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
        for method in methods:
            result.append((class_.name + '.' + show_info(method)))

    # print(', '.join(result))
    return result
    # This prints expected output
    # fo(x), A.fun(self,y), A._bo(self,y), A.NS(y,z), B.foo(self,z), B._bar(self,t)


# Get paste to work (but it doesn't recycle :( )
# source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756195/256662
from functools import reduce
def _reduce_concat(x, sep=""):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + sep + str(y), x)        
def paste(*lists, sep=" ", collapse=None):
    result = map(lambda x: _reduce_concat(x, sep=sep), zip(*lists))
    if collapse is not None:
        return _reduce_concat(result, sep=collapse)
    return list(result)

# this fails with recycling:
# paste("Hello", ["Ben", "Mike"]) # ['H Ben', 'e Mike'] # not what we want.
# paste(["Hello"], ["Ben", "Mike"]) # ['Hello Ben'] # not what we want.
# paste("a", ["Ben", "Mike"]) # ['a Ben'] # not what we want.

# gets all the py files from a root folder (excluding tests)
def get_all_py_files_no_tests(root):
    result = []

    # based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909998/256662
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for name in files:
            if name[-3:] == '.py' and ('tests' not in path):
                result.append(os.path.join(path, name))
                # print(os.path.join(path, name))
    return result


def merge_py_file_and_funcs(py_file):
    import numpy as np

    funcs = get_functions_and_methods(py_file)
    py_file_recycled = np.repeat(py_file, len(funcs))

    return paste(py_file_recycled, funcs)


def flatten(l):
    """
    # source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/256662
    """
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

def get_all_fun_from_root(root):
    py_files = get_all_py_files_no_tests(root)
    all_combos = flatten([merge_py_file_and_funcs(py_file) for py_file in py_files])
    return all_combos

# source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136703/256662
def search_replace_in_list(words, search = "", replace = ""):
    return [w.replace(search, replace) for w in words]
# search_replace_in_list(["abs", "abbfe"], "b", "_b_")
# ['a_b_s', 'a_b__b_fe']


def given_pkg_return_funs_and_methods(pkg):
    if type(pkg) is str:
        pkg_folder = pkg
    else:
        # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12154601/256662
        import os
        import inspect

        pkg_folder = os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(pkg))
        
    all_items = get_all_fun_from_root(pkg_folder)
    cleaned_all_items = search_replace_in_list(all_items, pkg_folder)
    return cleaned_all_items
```

Example of usage:

```
import numpy
given_pkg_return_funs_and_methods(numpy)
```

This returns:

```
['/__config__.py get_info(name)',
 '/__config__.py show)',
 '/_globals.py _NoValueType.__new__(cls)',
 '/_globals.py _NoValueType.__reduce__(self)',
 '/_globals.py _NoValueType.__repr__(self)',
 '/_pytesttester.py _show_numpy_info)',
 '/_pytesttester.py PytestTester.__init__(self,module_name)',
 '/_pytesttester.py PytestTester.__call__(self,label,verbose,extra_argv,doctests,coverage,durations,tests)',
 '/conftest.py pytest_configure(config)',
 '/conftest.py pytest_addoption(parser)',
 '/conftest.py pytest_sessionstart(session)',
 '/conftest.py pytest_itemcollected(item)',
 '/conftest.py check_fpu_mode(request)',
 '/conftest.py add_np(doctest_namespace)',
 '/ctypeslib.py _num_fromflags(flaglist)',
 '/ctypeslib.py _flags_fromnum(num)',
##### Etc...
```

Nicer printing can be done using something like:

```
import some_package # or use `some_package = a\direct\path`
all_fun = given_pkg_return_funs_and_methods(some_package)
for i in all_fun:
    print(i)
```

This solution used the following stackoverflow references:

- [How to list all classes and methods/functions in a specific .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73239026/256662)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756195/256662
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909998/256662
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/256662
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136703/256662
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12154601/256662